# Wordpress meta query errors happening

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Hello stackoverflow community. I need help, I set for user what he can see, lets say `2015january` journals. In custom posts I set post that it is `2015january`. And then I'm trying to print all posts with meta value from my array like this:

```
$arrreyy = get_field('Whatcansee','user_'.get_current_user_id());
$args=array(
    'post_type' => 'journals',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'choose_years', // name of custom field
            'value' => $arrreyy, // matches exactly "red"
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);          
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

But I get an error: `Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given meta.php 1455`

My `$arrreyy` is: `Array ([0]=>2015january [1]=2015february)`

If I search by `'value' => 2015january` - everything is ok. But when array I get this error. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use an array for `value` when `compare` is `LIKE`. [From the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query):

> **value** *(string|array)* - Custom field value. It can be an array only when `compare` is `'IN'`, `'NOT IN'`, `'BETWEEN'`, or `'NOT BETWEEN'`.

Using `LIKE` here is resulting in an error, since WordPress is trying to `trim()` an array.

Comment: So what should i do in order to filter posts?

Comment: Can't use just use the `IN` comparison, instead of `'LIKE'`?

Comment: If i change 'LIKE' to 'IN'. Query ain't finding nothng...         array(
            'key' => 'choose_years', // name of custom field
            'value' => $arrreyy, // matches exactly "red"
            'compare' => 'IN'
        )
Or should i explode or implode?